# Time dependent workflow email alert - dropping fields

Tags: visualforce, workflow, email-template

I have a visualforce email template.

When I send it via the 'send test and verify merge fields' button it populates correctly with all fields.

When I send it via an immediate workflow action - it populates correctly.

When I send it via a time-dependent workflow action, the email is sent, but some of the fields from the object are not displayed on the email.

What could be causing this difference in behavior given that the email template is the same and the only difference is whether it is a time-dependent or immediate workflow?

Comment: Not sure about the reason, Can you try this workaround? From time dependent workflow, try to run a process builder's process  (may be through a field update) and send email from that process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with permissions - since I was the one editing a record to generate the workflow and email alert, it was using my permission set, whereas the timed emails were automatically being edited by a guest user that didn't have the necessary permissions.

Still not 100% on how it is decided which permission set is used for workflows...